# upload files to google cloud storage using Blobstore API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am trying to upload files from the browser to GCS. 
I am using `blobstore` API to upload files.

I went through the documentation and I could not find how to upload `blob` to GCS.

How do I get the file from `blobkey` so that I could upload it to GCS.

JSP side

```
 <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>"
       method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="myFile">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

servletSide

```
 Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
 BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");
 GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
 GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, "exampleFile");
 GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/plain")
                          .acl("authenticated-read")
                          .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
                          .build();
 gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options, /*File from the blob key */);
```

Can any one help me how to save the files into GCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after going through the java docs i was able to figure out 
how to upload blob and multiple blob file to gcs.

```
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>"
   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myFile">
 <input type="file" name="myFile2">
 <input type="file" name="myFile3">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

servlet side

instead of getting upload blobkey info

```
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobkeylist = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
```

i got blobInfos

```
Map<String, List<BlobInfo>> blobsData = blobstoreService.getBlobInfos(request);
for (String key : blobsData.keySet())
    {
        for(BlobInfo blob:blobsData.get(key))
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)blob.getSize()];
            BlobstoreInputStream in = new BlobstoreInputStream(blob.getBlobKey());
            in.read(b);

            GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
            GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, "/testFolder3/"+blob.getFilename());
            GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
            .mimeType(blob.getContentType())
            .acl("authenticated-read")
            .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
            .build();

            gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options,ByteBuffer.wrap(b));
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

this one worked.
im not sure if it is the best solution, but its working.

Answer (score 0):

When you see a blobkey, the file is already uploaded to GCS. You can resave it with different options, if you want, but you don't have to upload it again - it's already in your bucket.

Comment: You said, 'you can resave the file to GCS with different options', May I know, how that can be possible. Thanks.

Comment: `GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName, objectName);`  Then you define your own GcsFileOptions, and use `GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService().createOrReplace(fileName, options);`

Comment: Andrei - Thanks for your info. In this case, The filename should be same as already uploaded one. Is there any provision that you know to change the fileName of the file already uploaded to GCS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save a new file with a new name. Remember to delete the old one if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage (you need to provide createUploadUrl with UploadOptions that has googleStorageBucketName set to the destination bucket).